# Streaming (vídeo) não pausar ao dar refresh na página

Tags: javascript, streaming

Preciso fazer um player (streaming) ao navegar entre as páginas, que ele não pause, como se fosse algo externo, só que tem em todas as páginas, um exemplo, seria o chat do facebook, que podemos ir mudando de página, e ele sempre fica da mesma forma.

Fiz um teste adicionando um iframe do youtube no chat do facebook e dei play no mesmo, e navegando entre outras páginas do próprio facebook, o vídeo nem chegar a pausar, como se fosse uma página externa, que não tem a ver com a principal, sabem me dizer se isso é uma funcionalidade do próprio browser, ou alguma forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 2):

Você poderia construir a sua aplicação como "single page", o conteúdo seria recarregado e seu vídeo ficaria um uma área estática. 
Dei uma olhada rápida no facebook e aparentemente é construída assim. Se você abrir o debug do browser vai perceber que a pagina não é recarregada totalmente quando clica em um link.

Dê uma olhada nesse link para ter umas idéias.

http://www.webdesign-inspiration.com/web-designs/style/single-page

Comment: Estou dando uma olhada a respeito de "history.pushState", acho que é bem o que estou precisando: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history